# write input of string in list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

every time i press enter key shows me

```
[]
none
```

i do not know why and i want to write number 6 instead of passing it as a parameter stackoverflow do not accept the question until i write anything but i write all what i know i use pytharm by the way 
i want the output something like that

```
6
baraclona
madrid 
spain
africa
USA
UAE
```

code

```
def OutputMostPopularDestination( count):
    test = input(count)
    inputs =[]
    for i in test:
        string_input = input()
        inputs.append(string_input)

    print(inputs)

print(OutputMostPopularDestination(6))
```

Comment: There are several things wrong with your program. Please read and follow along with the entire [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/). After you finish, you will be able to write this program without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems in your program. Here are some of them:

- You pass in `count`, but you use `test` in your loop
- `input()` returns a `str`, but you use it as an `int`. A conversion is required.
- The typical counting `for` loop is like `for i in range(count)`. A call to `range()` is required.
- Functions with no `return` statement implicitly return `None`. A `return inputs` is required.

Try this:

```
def OutputMostPopularDestination( ):
    test = int(input("How many lines?"))
    inputs =[]
    for i in range(test):
        string_input = input()
        inputs.append(string_input)

    return inputs

print(OutputMostPopularDestination())
```

Comment: You are Mr @Rob I will read the tutorial again thanks